# How do I bring FullCalendar(v5) into Ember.js(v4) to render within a component?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, fullcalendar-5

I'm trying to integrate FullCalendar (v5) with an Ember.JS (4.2) app, and am able to get things to work if I just import the library via CDN and inline / hard code it -- however if I attempt to break it out into a component, I get an empty page.

### Inline Works

I'm able to render the calendar and an example event if I import FullCalendar via CDN links, and bind it an html element with the id of "calendar" on page load, as follows:

```html
<!-- Filename: index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <title>Client</title>
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

    {{content-for "head"}}
    <link integrity="" rel="stylesheet" href="{{rootURL}}assets/vendor.css" />
    <!-- TODO: Replace with npm/yarn package initiated within app config -->
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.10.2/main.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />

    {{content-for "head-footer"}}
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <!-- TODO: Move into component -->
    <div id="calendar"></div>

    {{content-for "body"}}

    <!-- TODO: Remove once replacing import via npm/yarn package -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.10.2/main.min.js"></script>
    <!-- TODO: Move into component -->
    <script>
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
        
        var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
          initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
              headerToolbar: {
              left: 'prev,next today',
              center: 'title',
              right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
              },
          events: [
            {
              title: 'Kayak Tour',
              start: '2022-03-09T14:30:00',
              end: '2022-03-09T19:30:00',
            },
          ],
        });

        calendar.render();
      });
    </script>
    {{content-for "body-footer"}}
  </body>
</html>
```

[image: Works when inline]

### But How to Refactor into Component?

However, which I can't seem to understand a solution via Ember docs, is that if I try and setup the calendar within a component (see TODO's above), I only get a blank page and can't get the calendar to display.

For example, if I move the `<div id="calendar"></div>` into a component: `event-calendar.hbs`:

```html
<!-- Filename: components/event-calendar.hbs -->
<div id="calendar"></div>
```

But I'm not sure in its associated data file, how I am to bind to the div as I did in the index example above? E,g:

```js
// Filname: components/event-calendar.js
import Component from '@glimmer/component';

export default class EventCalendarComponent extends Component {
      // how do I bind to `#calendar` like I did in the index file above?
}
```

I've even tried keeping the JS in `index.html`, and moving the div into my component, which doesn't seem to render.

Ideally, in my primary view, I want to inject my calendar as a component as follows (and later pass in an events object):

```html
<!-- Filename: templates/index.hbs -->
{{page-title 'Home'}}
<div>
  <EventCalendar />
</div>
{{outlet}}
```

I suspect that the `<div id="calendar"></div>` does not exist in the DOM yet? Does anyone have any suggestions how I might get this basic example to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you'd want a component -- maybe a modifier -- because this is a behavior to add to an element specifically?

For example, using: https://github.com/ember-modifier/ember-modifier and these docs: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/initialize-es6

```js
// app/modifiers/calendar.js
import { modifier } from 'ember-modifier';
import { Calendar } from '@fullcalendar/core';

export default modifier((element, [overrideOptions]) => {
  let calendar = new Calendar(element, {
    initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
    ...overrideOptions,
    headerToolbar: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay',
      ...(overrideOptions.headerToolbar || {})
    },
    events: overrideOptions.events
      ? overrideOptions.events
      : [{
          title: 'Kayak Tour',
          start: '2022-03-09T14:30:00',
          end: '2022-03-09T19:30:00',
        }],

  });

  calendar.render();

  return () => {
    // if the calendar has a teardown function, you'd want to call that here
  }
}
```

and then anywhere in your app you can do:

```
<div {{calendar}}></div>
```

or

```
{{!-- defining assumed to exist on whichever 'this' is--}}
<div {{calendar this.calendarOptions}}></div>
```

Be sure to install ember-modifier and @fullcalendar/core and restart your dev server

Comment: This is awesome, I can't tell you how much I appreciate your time! Testing, I encounter an error after adding the @fullcalendar/core: (when ember builds via webpack): `ERROR in ./node_modules/@fullcalendar/common/main.css 4:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (4:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders`. Package is found, but I've been searching all over for how to config a loader for ember. I suspect config goes in `ember-cli-build.js`, but not finding examples.

Comment: Update: Thanks @NullVoxPopuli for all your assistance -- going to checkout `ember-auto-import` to see if resolves my css webpack issue. So appreciated!

Comment: did you make progress?

Comment: I was able to get the calendar to render!  QQ: Where would I define the data I'm passing in (e.g, `overrideOptions`?). I placed the calendar modifier into a template component `event_calendar.hbs` as `{{calendar}}`. Would I define the data in the data file, `event_calendar.js` and then set `overrideOptions` there as a `@tracked` property? TL;DR -- just having trouble understanding where I should define the data being passed into the modifier. This was a huge help unblocking me and I so sincerely appreciate your time!

Comment: Update: I was able to figure it out! I just needed to create data in my `event_calendar.js` file, e.g. `@tracked overrideOptions = {...my data...}` and then ensure that I had square brackets around the parameter in the modifier, e.g, `export default modifier((element, [overrideOptions]) => { ... }` in order to access from within my modifier. I modified the parameter to instead be `eventData` so I can just pass in an array of events...awesome!

Comment: congrats!!! always good when things get working <3